# Create running tot with OVER in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Sever 2014 I want to create a column with a running total with partition, but I can't get it to work. This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    a.ArtikelCode
    ,a.Omschrijving
    ,o.OrderNr
    ,o.Datum
    ,r.ProdItem
    ,o.Aantal
    ,(SUM(Aantal) OVER(PARTITION BY r.ProdItem ORDER BY r.ProdItem ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS Telling
FROM Artikel a
LEFT JOIN Receprt r ON r.ReqItem = a.ArtikelCode
LEFT JOIN [Order] o ON o.ArtikelCode = r.ProdItem
WHERE LEFT(a.ArtikelCode,1) = 'M'
GROUP BY r.ProdItem, o.ArtikelCode, a.ArtikelCode, o.Datum, o.Aantal, a.Omschrijving, o.OrderNr
ORDER BY a.ArtikelCode, r.ProdItem, o.datum
```

This gives me the following result:
[image]

As you can see, the column "Telling" does a sum on the "Aantal" column. For ArtikelCode "M01" And ProdItem "ART01" that goes well. But at record 8 it is still summing up. What I want is that it starts over again in record 8 with 2 and, In record 9 it should be 3 and in record 10 the sum in column "Telling" should be 10

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add `ArtikelCode` to your `PARTITION BY`

Comment: I think record 10 should be 8, not 10.

Comment: @kwv84, Use sum(Aantal) over(partition by ArtikelCode, ProdItem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you also want to partition by `ArtikelCode`.  I think you intend to order by `datum` as well . . . and the `rows` clause is unneeded because it is there by default:

```
 SUM(Aantal) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ArtikelCode, r.ProdItem
                   ORDER BY o.datum
                  ) as Telling
```